# How to cook Beansprouts so that they remain crispy

Tags: vegetables

I have tried different methods of cooking Beansprouts but I just never seem to get a consistent crunchy tasty end product. Can somebody please share a recipe or method because I absolutely love Beansprouts so much. (When they have been cooked by someone else)

Comment: Can you please explain more thoroughly the type of dish you're trying to create? I've never heard of a dish that's only bean sprouts other than something like one of the side dishes at Korean restaurants, and those certainly aren't crispy.

Answer (score 4):

I only know one way -- don't cook them.

I add them at the last second before serving.  If I want them to warm through slightly, I'll mix them into whatever else has been cooked before plating -- otherwise, I'll just add them on top as more of a garnish.

Comment: I did try eating them raw but not really to my taste. Thank you anyway, I appreciate all suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Stir fry them fast... Make sure they are dry before you begin, add the smallest amount of neutral oil; and a little sesame oil for flavor and smell... When the oils and pan are super hot, throw in the bean shoots... Keep them moving for no more than one minute... Serve immediately...

Korean dishes call for blanched bean shoots... Again work fast... Make sure that the beans are added and then removed for the fast boiling water extra fast. Shock them in running cold or iced water as soon as you are done...

In either case the objective is to maintain some level of crispness, but to remove the raw "green" flavor of uncooked bean shoots.

Comment: Wow thank you. I tried both methods with equal enjoyment. Probably slight preference for the Korean method but very happy with the results and now able to enjoy my own cooking a great deal more.

Comment: Koreans seem to prefer bean shoots made from soy beans... The root is somewhat tougher and stronger, and the bean is bigger and much stronger in flavor. Its crunchier than normal beans... Another shoot to try seems to be chick pea shoots... They are even nicer...